# Feed item in chat doesn't show the new Chem.SE logo

Tags: bug, design

When a new feed item pops up in chat, the logo shown is the old beta on rather than the new logo Chem.SE got on graduation.

[image]

Comment: I believe that this is just a server caching issue and should be resolved soon, but I'll double-check.